# Function to add up all the numbers from 1 to num

Tags: javascript

I think there could be a better version then my solution. My Solution is working just fine. I didn't like juggling of all values using for loop.

But I am particularly wondering, If there is nice and one line solution getting all values in array up to entered number from function.

```
function SimpleAdding(num) {
  var Fnum = [];
  for (var i = 1; i <= num; i++) {
    Fnum.push(i);
  }
  return Fnum.reduce(function(prevValue, currentValue) {
    return prevValue + currentValue;
  })
}
```

Comment: I like the "Simple" prefixing the most convoluted solution...

Comment: Your question isn't clear. Is it about adding ? Or about *"getting all values in array up to entered number from function"* ?

Comment: i wrote "Function to add up all the numbers from 1 to num" to make it clear what function is doing or what it for and afterwards i just asked about the particular part of question i was wondering..

Comment: Thanks for whoever up voted it! I'm relaxed now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I think there could be a better version then my solution.

use this formula

```
function SimpleAdding(num) {
    return num * (num+1) /2;
}
```

> If there is nice and one line solution getting all values in array up
>   to entered number from function

```
function SimpleAdding(num) {
  var Fnum = new Array(num).join().split(',').map(function(item, index){ return ++index;});

  return Fnum.reduce(function(prevValue, currentValue) {
    return prevValue + currentValue;
  })
}
```

Comment: `num++` is fine too, just saying.

Comment: I removed my downvote. Let's now just precise that using this SimpleAdding function would be retarded ^^

Comment: @DenysSéguret didn't get `sing this SimpleAdding function would be retarded` can you elaborate?

Comment: Well, you perfectly know it's very very slow for a simple computation

Comment: @DenysSéguret so you removed the upvote because you didn't like the question? or my solution?

Comment: @Mr.Alien done that, however it was just one character savings :) but has changed the value of num, isn't it?

Comment: +1 your solution is nice and brilliant. just wondering about `/2` in  `return num * (num++) /2;` and Sorry your answer is **incorrect** as well. because if i input SimpleAdding(12) => it give me answer 72 instead should give 78.

Comment: @gurvinder372 there you go with up vote. and waoo how come num++ != num+1 that's strange. Do you have any explanation for that? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Array#fill`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill) with [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

```
Array(num) // [undefined x num]
    .fill(0) // Array of `num` zeros
    .reduce((prev, curr, ind) => prev + (ind + 1), 0); // (ind + 1) is the number
```

```js
var num = 10;
var sum = Array(num).fill(0).reduce((prev, curr, ind) => prev + (ind + 1), 0);

console.log(sum);
document.body.innerHTML = sum;
```

1. Create an array of `n` elements using `Array()`
2. Fill the array by zeros, using `.fill`
3. To get the sum of elements use `.reduce` whose third parameter is the `index`. As `index` is zero-based, adding 1 to it will give the numbers from `1` to `n`.

Answer (score 0):

You can, for a *nice and one line solution getting all values in array up to entered number from function*, use [`Array.apply()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) and [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

```js
var array = Array.apply(null, { length: 10 }).map(function (_, i) { return i + 1; });
document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(array, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```